# How can we check whether empty partitions are present in Athena using lambda function code or query

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am trying to fetch whether partition is added or not to Athena table using lambda function code. But when I use
Select * from "table $partitions" where batch date ='yyyymmdd'
It is showing error because in lambda function " is not taking.
But with out " my code is not working.

Can someone suggest anything on this

Comment: Provide code snippet you used in lambda. Is it in python, Node.js? Also, provide error message you received.

Comment: Query = select * from {}."{}$partitions" WHERE batch_date = {} .format(databasename, tablename, batchdata)

Comment: query = "SELECT * FROM default.tb"
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output,
        }
    ) When I execute this it is showing response executed before assignment